# limits of ratios of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am reading the book on analysis by Thomson Bruckner Bruckner and teaching myself analysis. Below is a problem and I just wanted to confirm my reasoning as to why the argument is wrong. Here it goes.

Essentially choosing $|g(x) - M| < \frac{\epsilon}{2|f(x)| + 1}$ implies that if $f(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$ then $|g(x) - M|$ can be 
increasing as $x \rightarrow x_o$, since $\frac{\epsilon}{2|f(x)| + 1}$ is not constant. However, it still seems like $|f(x)| \frac{\epsilon}{2|f(x)| + 1} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. I am not sure what the error in the argument is. Is it just that $\frac{\epsilon}{2|f(x)| + 1}$ is not constant?
[image]

[image: Problem to Prove Limit of Ratios of Functions]

Comment: Can you include what theorem 5.17 is please?

Comment: @Arby, Added the theorem.

Comment: Tell us what $L,M$ are

Comment: @zhw, $lim_{x\rightarrow x_o} f(x) = L$ and $lim_{x \rightarrow x_o} g(x) = M$.

Comment: You should make that clear at the beginning of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is exactly what you say. When they say pick $\delta_2$ such that $|g(x)-M|$ is less than $\epsilon/(2|f(x)|+1)$ there is a problem.  Continuity only lets us require that $|g(x)-M|<\epsilon$ for a fixed value of $\epsilon$, not a function of $x$.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that was what it was but could not be sure.